# Как в Linux Mint 12 сделать автоматическое подключение vpn-интернета.

Tags: linux, linux-mint, ubuntu

Не получается сделать автоматическое подключение интернета (при загрузке системы). В настройках соответствующую "птичку" ставлю, но это "птичка" не сохраняется.В результате, после включения компьютера и загрузки Минт, приходится каждый раз нажимать на подключение к интернету и вводить пароль пользователя.Помогите автоматизировать процесс.

Answer (score 1):

Написать скрипт для запуска, что то типа ifstart <твое подключение> и добавить в запускаемые приложения

Answer (score 0):

Если не сработает на уровне пользовтеля предыдущий совет-покопайся в сторону рунлевелеов(runlevel) и сценариев с префиксами S и K.